# Problem displaying table using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, servlets

I have the servlet code below:

variables form_date, to_date and link_name were passed from another jsp.
form_date and to_date are obtained from a date range search. link name is obtained from a drop-down selection.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-1252");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>IP Core Downtime</h1>");
    out.println("<TABLE cellpadding=\"15\" border=\"1\" style=\"background-color: #ffffcc;\">");
    out.println("<tr>\n"
            + "        <td>VENDOR NAME</td>\n"
            + "        <td>LINK NAME</td>\n"
            + "        <td>BASKET</td>\n"
            + "        <td>TICKET NUMBER</td>\n"
            + "        <td>IMPACTED SERVICE</td>\n"
            + "        <td>CIRCUIT ID</td>\n"
            + "        <td>ISSUE REPORTED</td>\n"
            + "        <td>BEGIN TIME</td>\n"
            + "        <td>END TIME</td>\n"
            + "        <td>RCA</td>\n"
            + "        </tr>");

    try {

        String link_name = request.getParameter("link_name");
        String form_date = request.getParameter("form_date");
        String to_date = request.getParameter("to_date");
        Date beginDateParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(form_date);
        String beginDate = beginDateParsed.toString();


        Date endDateParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(to_date);
        String endDate = endDateParsed.toString();


        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/";
        String database = "orclpdb";
        String userid = "";
        String password = "";
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Class.forName(driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "select VENDOR_NAME,LINK_NAME,BASKET,TICKET_NUMBER,IMPACTED_SERVICE,CIRCUIT_ID,ISSUE_REPORTED,BEGIN_TIME,END_TIME,RCA from AATESTUSER.IP_CORE_AVAILABILITY_1 where BEGIN_TIME between To_Date(" + beginDate + ",'DD-MM-YY') and To_Date(" + endDate + ",'DD-MM-YY') and LINK_NAME='" + link_name + "'";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            out.println("<TR><TD>resultSet.getString(2)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(3)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(4)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(5)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(6)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(7)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(8)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(9)</TD>\n"
                    + "        <TD>resultSet.getString(10)</TD>\n"
                    + "        </TR>");

        }
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println("Driver caused Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");
    }

    out.close();
}
```

It is required for the servlet to generate table based on the jsp date range search and drop-down selection criteria. The problem is that only the table heading is generated. the body of the table shows error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. Adjustments to correct the code brings forth varying oracle errors.

Comment: Print the sql and share it here.

Comment: Never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: Another note: do not output HTML from the servlet. Use servlet as a controller to load and prepare the data, but then forward to JSP (or another template) to show the data. I.e. use the [Model-View-Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp) pattern.

Comment: @ Tajesh, please the generated page by the servlet is as follows:                            IP Core Downtime
Driver caused Exception : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
VENDOR NAME  LINK NAME  BASKET  TICKET NUMBER  IMPACTED SERVICE  CIRCUIT ID  ISSUE REPORTED  BEGIN TIME  END TIME  RCA

Comment: @Tajesh, running the same sql query on sql developer successfully generated the required rows and columns. the errors come up while using the same sql query in the servlet

Comment: @Jozef Chocholacek, thanks, I would go read up your suggestions. I am new to jsp  MVC patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your query string to wrap your `dates` in `single quotes(')` as they are strings and also make sure that the format which is specified in the `to_date` function matches with the format of passed string variables(`beginDate` and `endDate`):

```
String sql = "select VENDOR_NAME,LINK_NAME,BASKET,TICKET_NUMBER,IMPACTED_SERVICE,CIRCUIT_ID,ISSUE_REPORTED,BEGIN_TIME,END_TIME,RCA from AATESTUSER.IP_CORE_AVAILABILITY_1 where BEGIN_TIME between To_Date('" + beginDate + "','DD-MM-YY') and To_Date('" + endDate + "','DD-MM-YY') and LINK_NAME='" + link_name + "'";
```

Notice that I have wrapped the `beginDate` and `endDate` with single quotes.

Cheers!!

Comment: Hello Tajesh, I implemented the above. Now a new kind of error is popping up: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

Comment: That means you need to change the format of `TO_DATE` --> from `DD-MM-YY` to whatever your `beginDate` and  `endDate` format is. The best way is to print the query string and match the format of your variable and `TO_DATE` format parameter.

Comment: Thanks Tejash, Here are the outputs after printing these servlet variables. I discovered that link_name was null. Also, beginDateParsed and endDateParsed had a strange format as shown below. My database date format is of the form- 06-JUL-19, (the format required for the servlet output)

link_name:null 
form_date:2019-07-01 
to_date:2019-07-31 
beginDateParsed:Tue Jan 01 00:07:00 WAT 2019 
beginDate:Tue Jan 01 00:07:00 WAT 2019 
endDateParsed:Thu Jan 31 00:07:00 WAT 2019 
endDate:Thu Jan 31 00:07:00 WAT 2019 
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: How can I make the beginDateparsed have the expected format?

Comment: Also link_name which is supposed to be passed from the jsp drop down selection is obviously not being passed into the servlet.